# Square of number is not getting trained by Tesnsorflow js

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I was training the model with square of inputs

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

// Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

const inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
const outputs =  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256]


// Generate some synthetic data for training. (y = x*x)
const xs = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d(outputs, [outputs.length, 1]);

console.log(xs.print())
console.log(ys.print())


// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 250}).then(() => {
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([70], [1, 1])).print();
});
```

but Still, the output is not coming correct or close to correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the model.

you want to learn a non-linear relationship with a linear regression (your model is linear).

To learn efficiently you need to add more layers and a non-linear activation function between them.

*e.g.*

```js
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1], activation> 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation= 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation= 'relu'}));
```